# Why can't infrared rays go through the atmosphere?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, soft-question, atmospheric-science, absorption, infrared-radiation

Why can't infrared rays reach the earth? Why can't they pass through the atmosphere?

Comment: When you step out in to the sunshine, do you not feel warmer? Seems that IR goes through the atmosphere (not to say that some is not absorbed there, with due consideration for molecular absorption mechanisms).

Comment: @JonCuster A large fraction of the (wide!) band that astronomers call infrared is largely absorbed by the atmosphere so the texts say things like "infrared telescopes need to be placed at high altitude or in space", not withstanding that non-trivial parts of the near and middle infrared have high transmission coefficients through the atmosphere.

Comment: @dmckee - sure, but a non-trivial amount gets through, as well. For the telescopes they get greedy ;) and want good signal to noise (and it depends a lot on what wavelengths they want to see - molecular absorption of, e.g. water, is a major problem).

Comment: Sites like [Terra & Aqua Satellites: Earth Observing System](http://uregina.ca/piwowarj/Satellites/TerraAqua.html) give the atmospheric transmission spectrum.

Comment: @JonCuster Sorry. That wasn't a criticism but an explanation of why students might come to us with a blanket statement of this kind when something that broad isn't really warranted. I believe that we are in agreement.

Comment: @dmckee - I believe so as well. Peter's comment pointing to the transmission spectrum is the better physics answer compared with mine.

Answer (score 1):

Gases in the atomsphere have natural resonant frequencies at which they vibrate if stimulated to do so. To stimulate the vibration, a frequency at, or near, the resonant frequency must be applied. When you push a child on a swing with the same frequency as the swing's natural frequency, the child/swing will "absorb" that energy and swing higher .

Carbon dioxide molecules, for one, have their resonance frequency in the infrared. So when light from the sun strikes the atmosphere, much of the infrared is absorbed into vibrations of these molecules. It is re-emited again but in random directions instead of the path it would have taken straight to the Earth's surface. Some of re-emision reaches Earth but the majority of the absorbed infrared is re-emited back into space.

Turn this around. Much of the shorter wave radiation that easily passes through the atmosphere strikes the earth and is re-emited as infrared. Instead of escaping into space, much of it is also absorbed by molecules such as CO2. A significant percentage of that randomly directed re-emmision heads back toward Earth to melt glaciers.

Comment: Thnk a lott @bpedit